# Control segue destination Back button Navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have 4 views embedded in a Navigation Bar:

VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4

I need Back button from VC3 to be segued to VC1 instead of VC2. I have searched to implement this option but I wasn't successful. Is it possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you add a segue to the VC1 from VC3?

Comment: Because I need to perform this sequence, but I need VC3 Back button to be back at VC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the behavior of the back button if you want it to keep it's normal appearance, but you could resort to a dirty fix (I'm not familiar with a better way of doing this) if you can't organize your application better. It involves editing the navigation stack directly and removing the view controller you don't need from it.

It's not a recommended way of handling this, but it gets the things done:

```
NSMutableArray *myNavigationStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[myNAvigationStack removeObjectAtIndex:<yourViewControllerExtraIndex>];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationStack;
```

Make sure you get the right index (0 being your rootViewController), and to handle your memory properly.

Probably the best way of going around this is to design the architecture of your application to avoid this kind of behavior completely.